# Visual Studio 12 VSIXInstaller reports a FileNotFoundException when running in DSC Script

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, dsc

I'm writing a Powershell DSC script so I can easily configure development environments. I'm trying to get Visual Studio 2012 Addons to install without opening the GUI.

I've downloaded the Specflow .vsix file. When I run

```
 & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" /q C:\Users\Public\Downloads\TechTalk.SpecFlow.Vs2010Integration.vsix
```

on the Powershell command prompt, it works without a hitch. But if I try to do the same thing in a DSC Script resource, I run into problems. Copying and pasting the command above into SetScript results in VSInstaller.exe results in the command never finishing.

I therefore tried the following, based on the Choco [Install-VSIX](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/c798ae3a1b79101814599143a0ed416a69dc13ff/src/chocolatey.resources/helpers/functions/Install-Vsix.ps1) cmdlet:

```
Script installSpecflowVS {
        SetScript  = {          
            $specUrl  = 'https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9915524d-7fb0-43c3-bb3c-a8a14fbd40ee/file/79327/7/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Vs2010Integration.vsix'
            $outfile  = 'C:\Users\Public\DownloadsTechTalk.SpecFlow.Vs2010Integration.vsix'
            wget $specUrl -outfile $outfile 
            $psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
            $psi.FileName='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe'
            $psi.Arguments="/q $outfile"
            $s = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
            $s.WaitForExit()
            return $s.ExitCode
      }
      TestScript = { return $False }
      GetScript  = { return $True }
}
```

In this case, the command completes, but VSIXInstall.exe throws a FileNotFound error which I can see from the log created in in C:\Windows\Temp\

```
1/18/2017 10:51:51 AM - Searching for applicable products...
1/18/2017 10:51:51 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
1/18/2017 10:51:51 AM - System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.GetScopePaths(String applicationPath, String suffixOrName, String vsVersion, Boolean isLogged, Boolean isForIsolatedApplication)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.CreateForApplication(String applicationPath)
 at VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionManager(SupportedVSSKU sku)
 at VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionManagerForApplicableSKU(SupportedVSSKU supportedSKU, IInstallableExtension installableExtension, List`1 applicableSKUs)
 at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
 at VSIXInstaller.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
```

The file is definitely there; if I supply VSInstaller with something that doesn't exist it gives the following error instead

```
1/18/2017 10:21:45 AM - VSIXInstaller.InvalidCommandLineException: Path to vsix file 'outfile' is invalid or you don't have required access permissions. Please check the path is valid and you have required access permissions.
```

The script is running locally on a Windows 7 SP1 virtual machine with Powershell 5. I'm executing it using Powershell ISE with Admin privileges.

There is obviously something different about scripts running via DSC Set-Script. Any ideas how to fix to fix it? Or another way of doing it?

Comment: Have you succeeded? I have the same desire. Trying to write a DSC configuration for dev machines on-boarded to Azure Automation account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSIX is per user you need to tell DSC which user to install this as using `PSDscRunAsCredential` (added in PowerShell 5.0).

Example, where `$credential` is the credentials for the user that you want to install the VSIX for.

```
Script installSpecflowVS {
        SetScript  = {          
            $specUrl  = 'https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9915524d-7fb0-43c3-bb3c-a8a14fbd40ee/file/79327/7/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Vs2010Integration.vsix'
            $outfile  = 'C:\Users\Public\DownloadsTechTalk.SpecFlow.Vs2010Integration.vsix'
            wget $specUrl -outfile $outfile 
            $psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
            $psi.FileName='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe'
            $psi.Arguments="/q $outfile"
            $s = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
            $s.WaitForExit()
            return $s.ExitCode
      }
      TestScript = { return $False }
      GetScript  = { return $True }
      PSDscRunAsCredential = $credential
}
```

Please also see [Securing the `MOF` File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/securemof) on how to properly encrypt the `MOF` file so you don't leak your credentials.